# What skills only use the main-hand for damage calculations?

Tags: diablo-iii

What skill and rune combinations only use the main-hand for damage calculation? An example is the *Sprint* / *Run like the wind* combination.

I'm interested in all dual-wielding characters: Barbarian, Monk, Demon Hunter.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with my question?

Comment: I do not believe there are any skills that use only the main-hand for damage; it would defeat the purpose of dual-wielding entirely.

Comment: @fbueckert See the second answer on http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/31226/when-dual-wielding-weapons-how-is-damage-calculated-for-skills-that-do-x-weapo?rq=1

Comment: @bwarner I have learned something new!

Comment: As far as I could observe, Barb Leap uses only the main hand for damage calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of some skills to use only main hand damage was [decided by Blizzard](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/4216984727#4) since the beta patch 13 so players wouldn't have to time attacks for higher damage (by using skills right after weaker weapon had been used). If you want to read the notes, the Blizzard link doesn't work any more but I [found a copy](http://diablo.incgamers.com/blog/comments/diablo-3-beta-patch-13-official-notes) at Incgamers.

I'm not going to try and provide a list of skills; instead I will quote Bashiok (Blizzard CM):

> as far as I'm aware, "certain skills" is actually just any skill that uses weapon damage as a factor.

Interestingly, someone created a [thread on battle.net](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/6146794700) about this very recently - I agree with stormcontrol's post there that *spammable skills without CD alternate damage, while others don't*.

Thanks for asking this question, it was an eye-opener since I had a very different impression on the rarity of skills using only the main hand for damage.